# To which subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ does $g$ belong?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be a continuous function and let $a>0$. For any $i\in\{1,\dots, n\}$, let
$$ g_i(x):=\begin{cases}
a &\hbox{ if } f_i(x)\ge a\\
-a &\hbox{ if } f_i(x)\le -a\\
f_i(x) &\hbox{ if } f_i(x)\in (-a, a).
\end{cases} $$

Then, define
$$g(x) = (g_1(x),\dots, g_n(x)).$$

I apologize for the possibly dumb question, but in which subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is contained the function $g$?

I mean, which is the set $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $g(x)\in A$?

I would have said that $A= [-a, a]^n$, but my answer was marked as wrong.

Anyone could help with that?

Comment: I am not sure what order you are using, but if it is componentwise then $g$ is not fully defined.

Comment: The definition for $g$ is confusing. $f(x)$ is an $n$-dimensional vector, and $a$ seems to be a scalar. So the operation $f(x) \geq a$ isn't properly defined.

Comment: Perhaps you haven't stated the question correctly? If the codomain (range) of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}^n$, as you have written, then what does $f(x) \ge a$ mean?

Comment: I apologize everyone, question edited.

Comment: You are right that every element will be in the set $[-a, a]^n$, so maybe the corrector wanted something more specific? The problem is that I don't see a better way to characterise the range of $g$ in a simple manner without pretty much rewriting/repurposing the definition of $g$... $\left(f_1(\mathbb{R}^n) \cap [-a,a]\right) \times \cdots \times \left(f_n(\mathbb{R}^n) \cap [-a,a]\right)$ would be slightly more specific but still not an exact description of $A$.

Comment: @BrunoB Maybe just $[-a,a]^n \cap f(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Comment: @Sambo That's not quite true, the images of $g$ will not necessarily be images of $f$, for example there could be an $x$ such that $(a, 0, \dots, 0)$ is a $g(x)$ for some $x$ ($f(x) = (b, 0, \dots, 0)$ for some $|b| > |a|$) but such that it is not a $f(y)$ for any $y$.

Comment: I find the question not well posed: "in which subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is contained the function $g$?". Do you want any subset, or a subset with some special property, e.g. "the smallest"? in the latter case the answer is the image of $g$, in the former case any subset containing the image of $g$ is fine.

Comment: If the question were asked in exactly this way, then $\Bbb R^n$ itself would be a correct answer, as would be your answer of $[-a,a]^n$. But the wording of this question is so awkward, that I suspect you translated it from another language, In this case, I cannot guess the exact nature of the original question, or why your answer was incorrect. A tighter bound on the image of $g$ would be the set $\prod_i [-a,a]\cap \text{Img}(f_i)$, but in general, that is still not exactly the image.